# Android. Access needed to user's emails

Tags: android

I require access to the user's emails (inbox/sent folders) which are configured on the default Email app that comes with the OS. (not the gmail account used on the device, for that I have the gmail API). I need to parse the user's last emails and make some decisions based on that.
All this, of course, with the user's permission and knowledge.

Does the default email app expose these by any chance? Or at least expose the configurations for the email server so that I could retrieve them and user them to get the emails directly from the server? I want to make it as seamless as possible for the user, and not ask him to manually set-up the email in my app, but instead either get them directly from somewhere, or at least get the configurations for it.

Any solutions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "default email app".  The OS doesn't have this concept, there's no general API for it, and the actual email app installed can be different by OEM and model.  So no, this isn't generally possible.